# Select & move more than one file in filelist module?

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to select more than one file in the TYPO3  filelist module to move them to another directory. I use TYPO3 7.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible - the same way as within **Web>List** module, just enable the Clipboard box under the list and select **multi-selection mode** clipboard, that means Clipboard 1-3 instead of normal. In that case you'll see new checkboxes on each file's row. See screenshot (from 6.2)

[image]